# Tell hibernate to use the same case like the class fields for the sql statements

Tags: hibernate, jpa, glassfish-3

How can I configure the persistence.xml so that i don't need to put all these @Column annotations into my entities to let the entitymanager use exactly the same case as the fieldname. By default all the fieldnames are uppercase when i look into the log file.

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="INDICATE", schema="inet")
  public class Indicate implements Serializable {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      @Id 
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Column(name="indID", insertable = false, nullable=false, unique=true) private Long indID;
      @Column(name="prditmNO") private String prditmNO;
      @Column(name="indREASON") private Integer indREASON;
      @Column(name="indIP") private String indTCPIP;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own `org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy` for that requirement in Hibernate. The easiest way would be to override `org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy` and implement all methods that influence naming rules for tables and columns.

```
public class CaseSensitiveNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public String tableName(String name){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String columnName(String name){
        return name;
    }

}
```

Please keep in mind that there might be more methods that you want to override. See the JavaDocs for [further documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html) on this class.

Remember to register your custom `NamingStrategy` implementation in Hibernate. This can be done programatically when creating a `SessionFactory`.

```
Configuration config = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();
config.setNamingStrategy(new CaseSensitiveNamingStrategy());
SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
```

Alternatively you can use the declarative way to register a custom `NamingStrategy` setting the property `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy` to the full qualified class name of your `NamingStrategy` implementation like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy"
          value="stackoverflow.CaseSensitiveNamingStrategy"/>
```

Comment: I just figured out that Glassfish is not using hibernate. It's by default using toplink. There I found a DecriptorCustomizer. Is that the same procedure there?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JPA 2.0, the spec says:

It is possible to specify that all database identifiers in use for a persistence unit be treated as delimited identifiers by specifying the `<delimited-identifiers/>` element within the
persistence-unit-defaults element of the object/relational xml mapping file. If the
`<delimited-identifiers/>` element is specified, it cannot be overridden.